# If you have a T3 dedicated line do you need a VPN?

Tags: networking

Is this redundant or can you run VPN on a T3 dedicated line?  Do you still need security protection on the T3 line?

I was going to put VPN on my T3 line in my project, but after reading it through it just seemed unnecessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Where does your T3 lead to? The same place as the endpoint of your VPN?

- If the answer is 'No' then yes, you still want the VPN.
- If the answer is 'Yes' then consider how sensitive the data is (or if you are scared of your ISP listening in). If it is sensitive, then encrypt it. E.g. via a VPN **or** via another method.

Comment: It's going to the same place.  It's a class project, not RL.  I will include VPN in with the T3 line.  I'm encrypting the data with an ESP protocol called Advanced Encryption Standard.  I was going to use the Diffie-Hellman under the IKE protocol, but at this point I just want to get this over with if you know what I mean.  I hope AES works with everything I've included...no conflict.   :)